# fullcalendar, can i add location from gcal and can i give different colors based on different location events (from the same calendar)

Tags: fullcalendar

this is my code, the calendar and events display correctly but i want to give them more color and a location, can somebody please help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset='utf-8' />
<link href='fullcalendar-3.8.0/fullcalendar.min.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<link href='fullcalendar-3.8.0/fullcalendar.print.min.css' rel='stylesheet' media='print' />
<script src='fullcalendar-3.8.0/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-3.8.0/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-3.8.0/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar-3.8.0/gcal.min.js'></script>
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },

            displayEventTime: true, // don't show the time column in list view
            editable: true,       defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            googleCalendarApiKey: 'private', 
            // Key van de google calender 
            events: { url:'private' },
            eventClick: function(event) {
                // opens events in a popup window
                window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=700,height=600');
                return false;
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 40px 10px;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;   
    }
    #loading {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: 10px;   
    }

   #calendar {
       max-width: 900px;
       margin: 0 auto;   }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='loading'>loading...</div>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if those fields are returned by google in its JSON then yes you can. Use fullCalendar's eventRender callback to manipulate what gets displayed on the calendar for each event - at that point you have access to the event's properties and can use that to manipulate the event HTML.

Comment: I think they return location because I found code in the gcal.js file but i don't know how to write the eventrender code, could you please help.     
        return {
            id: item.id,
            title: item.summary,
            start: item.start.dateTime || item.start.date,
            end: item.end.dateTime || item.end.date,
            url: url,
            location: item.location,
            description: item.description

Comment: There's an example in the docs: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/ . Also if you inspect the event element on your calendar you'll see its HTML structure, and know where you can insert things. See if you can work it out from that. If you get stuck, post your attempt here and I'll help you fix it.

Comment: i've found that the "location" is inside the event container but isn't displaying in fc-content, but i don't know how to change that with event render

Comment: That's because you have to append it to the content yourself using JavaScript. You can easily google how to do that using JS / jQuery. Like I said, if you research and try something, you'll probably find it's not very difficult. But if you do get stuck, post your attempt here and I can help with it.